# Como puedo comparar el valor de una variable tipo string con un arreglo tipo string?

Tags: java

Lo que pasa es que tengo que buscar una cadena de datos dentro de el y después imprimir en pantalla en que parametros del arreglo esta y lo que pasa es que dentro del caso 3, no me deja compararlos con un if, agradecería que me ayudaran con esto

```
Scanner f = new Scanner(System.in);
        int fil,col,selec,l;
        String v;
String matriz[][] = new String [fil][col];
        String mat[][] = new String [fil][col];
do{

....

    case 3:
                System.out.print("Inserte cadena a buscar: ");
                f.nextLine();
                v = f.nextLine();
                for(int x=0;x<fil;x++)
                {
                    for(int y=0;y<col;y++)
                    {
                        if(matriz[x][y] == matriz[x][y] && matriz[x][y] == v)
                        {
                            System.out.println("La posicion es: matriz["+x+"]["+y+"] = "+matriz[x][y]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Además de la tautología `matriz[x][y] == matriz[x][y]` que en realidad no te afecta ya que siempre es `true` no veo nada raro.
Intenta revisar los indices. Creo recordar que las matrices se manejan `[columna][fila]`. Así que si `fil` y `col` tienen valores que pueden salirse de los índices te va a dar error.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma de comparar Strings es el método **equals()**.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [][] arr = {{"1", "2", "3"}, {"4", "5"}, {"6", "7"}};
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            if(arr[i][j].equals("2")) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: A pesar que esta puede ser la solución que el OP busca, deberías de agregar algún ejemplo para que no parezca un comentario.

Comment: Por supuesto, gracias!